# Converting nested JSON to SQLite / CSV

Tags: json, sqlite, csv, nested

I know this question has been asked numerous times. I have looked at various similar questions and a variety of answers for them, however I was not able to reach a good result. It might even not be possible, given the source files.

There are some data files from the game Dual Universe which I need to use to build an Industry tool. They are located [here](https://github.com/AstronIsTaken/du-craft/tree/main/data) and are nested data JSON files.
My tool uses SQLite to store and use data, and I am far enough into development to make the switch to another solution a pain, therefore I am looking at converting data from those JSON files into something that SQLite could use. All online converters either error out or produce a CSV monstrosity with a few rows and hundreds of columns, which wouldn't really be an issue unless the headers would be totally mangled.

Unfortunately I have no code to show, since this is solely related to a storage conversion which needs to be performed using an external tool.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am still a beginner (learning Java and SQL at the same time), and I have tried to solve for most of yesterday, but I am stuck.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html?

Comment: The question is unclear. You *at least* need to show the concrete database model you're aiming for. JSON is just a data storage format, it can be converted to *anything* including tables in a relational database. It's not a question of it JSON can be converted, it's a question of what precisely you want to convert it into.

Comment: Fair enough.
Let's look at one example, the raw data for the Talent Tree.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AstronIsTaken/du-craft/main/data/skillsAccordion.json

Comment: Edit (pressed Enter by mistake):
I want to convert it to a table where outermost entry (e.g. "name": "Pures") repeats for each inner entry (e.g. "name": "Basic Ore Refining") and so on.

Thus we will in the end have

type | name | tier | subject | class | amount | skill
Pures | Basic Ore Refining | 1 | item | input | 0.03 | Pure Aluminium
Pures | Basic Ore Refining | 1 | item | input | 0.03 | Pure Carbon
...
and so on.

Of course, once I have it in this format (be it SQLite or CSV), I would be able to further alter it (for example, change headers).